# what is difference between Mansikāro and Vitakā

Tags: jhana

[I have asked this question earlier](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/45737/what-is-difference-between-nimitta-and-vitaka-and-their-relation-to-manasikara)
but still not clear...so asking this again...
This time be specific on mansikaro and vitaka..

people says vitaka is directed attention and mansikaro is always termed as attention..

can we say vitaka is  directed mansikaro.?

Santa100 given good pointer to abhidhmma in his answer.

following questions are related to his answer.

After searching for vitaka in abhidhamma.. I found two major difference.

mansikaro is universal.. where vitaka is not.. can someone explain whats that means.

[vitaka is also sankappa](https://www.dhammawheel.com/viewtopic.php?t=32599). Can someone explain how.?

Answer (score 1):

> what is difference between Mansikāro and Vitakā

A few lines of explanation won't be able to fully describe these 2 important concepts. Please refer to [CMOA](https://store.pariyatti.org/comprehensive-manual-of-abhidhamma-ebook)'s Chapter II: Compendium of Mental Factors, where it analyses those factors in great details. But just in brief, below is the key passage:

> "Manasikara should be distinguished from Vitakka: while the former turns its concomitants towards the object, the latter applies them onto the object. Manasikara is an indispensable cognitive factor present in all states of consciousness while vitakka is a specialized factor which is not indispensable to cognition."

Comment: that link does not work.. However above paragraph is on wiki.. and I am reading it since one year..I still dont understand.

Comment: Doubt is  are they  same or different.

Comment: can we say vitaka is directed mansikaro.?   .. like man is mammal... vitaka is mansikaro..???

Comment: abhidhamma says mansikaro is universal and vitaka is not... what does that mean?

Comment: it also says vitaka is sankappa... How?

Comment: @enRaiser, i've updated the CMOA link. After clicking the link, simply scroll down until you see the Download Free PDF button and click it to download. I've recommended you read the chapter first, it should clear up your many questions.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question for the Jhana-attainer who beginning on the insight meditation. Jhana makes wholesome strong enough to see the truth.

I have ask similar question to the Tipitaka-memorizer, ven. Pa-auk. He answer me "meditate the concentration meditation".

However, according to Pali...

Vitakka is carrying mind and mind factors to do their duty on the object.

Vicara is  keeping carrying, again and again, mind and mind factors to do their duty on the object.

Manasikara is choosing the environment to do mind and mind factor's duty on the object.

Adhimokha is deciding the environment to do mind and mind factor's duty on the object.

Viriya is keeping the same environment to do mind and mind factor's duty on the object.

Sati is not forget not ignore the wholesome mind's object. It is keeping only wholesome mind and wholesome mind factors to do their duty on the object.

Etc, see the path of purification in pali version.